# Prevent page expired message in ASP.NET Webforms when user click back button with no-cache set

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am currently working on a C# ASP.NET Webforms project and during our testing we have encountered a issue which has come around when making a change to the cache policy on the site.

We have been told that we need to use no-cache in Cache Control which means if the user click the back button they will get the Page Expired warning. The only reason to click back would be if you wanted to start again so we have a Start Again button but during testing a few notes have been made that the tester has clicked the back button and received this error.

I have a had a good look around and trying to find a solution that works is proving to pretty difficult.

The ideal action would be when the user clicks the back button in the browser it just takes them back to the Default.aspx page and reloads it as it the user has clicked the Start Again button which is just a simple hyperlink.

Any suggestions on how to overcome this issue? Ideally I do not want to disable the back button in the browser just force the page to reload if it is expired, it doesn't need to resubmit the data.

I am unable to use GET as well for the form data as there is a lot of information to display which I know is one solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this is detects if the back button is being used and then you can redirect to your home page.

[https://www.shivrajan.com/how-to-detect-back-button-click-in-browser/#:~:text=how%20to%20detect%20back%20button%20click%20in%20browser.,user%20click%20F5%20or%20reload%20button%20of%20browser](https://www.shivrajan.com/how-to-detect-back-button-click-in-browser/#:%7E:text=how%20to%20detect%20back%20button%20click%20in%20browser.,user%20click%20F5%20or%20reload%20button%20of%20browser).

This should resolve your POST issue with the no-cache turned on.

Comment: Perfect, the 2nd example works perfectly. Using a simple redirect in the example I can make it work just like the user clicking the start again button.